# Fillet like in 3ds max

Tags: modeling, geometry, bevel

In 3ds max you can turn this[image]

to this [image]

with Fillet button.

In Blender there only bevel and it does not work anything like fillet in 3ds max.
[image]

It looks more like cancer grow...

Is there a way to make this look good in blender?

Comment: Isn't that curve in Max and mesh in Blender?

Comment: Yes, i think so ... blender cant do 90 degree rotation in curves so i didnt think of that...

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to use curve tools as mesh tools. The results may be different!

This Geonode setup bevels curve and only after that extrudes a circle around:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you have this kind of tool in Blender, but if you cut off your pipe you could use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* tool and tweak the values in order to get the bend:

[image]